# why protected becomes private to other classes in different package of subclass

Tags: java

why protected becomes private to other classes in different package of subclass .but it is still protected in same package of super class.

```
package a;
class A
{
  protected a;
}

package b;
class B extends A
{
  B()
{
  System.out.println(a);
}
}

class C
{
  C()
  {
    System.out.println(new B().a);//error
   }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Because the package is the "visibility limit" of the `protected` access modifier for non-related classes. See the docs here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html:

> The protected modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed
>   within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by
>   a subclass of its class in another package.

As you can see from the above, you are neither in the case of subclass, nor in the case of same package.

Comment: "*C is neither a subclass of A nor in the same package*" Did you just plagiarize me?

Comment: @user1329572: No, I did not, I seems to be a coincidence. I'll rephrase it if it bothers you.

Comment: It's hardly an original sentence. I wouldn't rephrase.

Comment: @user1329572: Well I guess it's better this way. Who knows how some other viewers will react if they see identical paragraphs. :)